# React infinite loading of data till data is there from backend--fixed data is coming on every request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, infinite

I have a react component with infinite loading functionality where i get fixed around 13 records every time i make a request to backend.
I need to send only page number to backend to fetch data and only data is coming from backend on that specific pageNumber.
And i need to show loading spinner on scrolling down as data is getting loaded or till data is there.
I wrote some code but its not working perfectly.
Any guidance is appreciated . I am a freshman in react and i am lost.

```
const TableBody = (props) => {
      const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
      const [manifestList, setManifestList] = useState([]);
      const [initialmanifestLength, setInitialmanifestLength] = useState();
      const [normalManifestList, setNormalManifestList] = useState([]);
      const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      }, []);

      function getManifests(pageNo){
        setIsFetching(true);
        if(pageNo == 1)
        {
          axios.get(props.urls.list, { params: { page: pageNo } }).then(res => {
            setManifestList([...manifestList, ...res.data]);
            setNormalManifestList(res.data);
            setInitialmanifestLength(res.data.length);
            setIsFetching(false)
          });
        }
        else{
          axios.get(props.urls.list, { params: { page: pageNo } }).then(res => {
            setManifestList([...manifestList, ...res.data]);
            setNormalManifestList(res.data);
            setIsFetching(false)
          });
        }

      }

      useEffect(() => {
        getManifests(page);
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
        if (!isFetching) return;
          getManifests(page);
      }, [page, isFetching]);

      function handleScroll() {
        if (
          window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !==
            document.documentElement.offsetHeight ||
          isFetching
        )
          return;
        let pageNo = page + 1;
        setPage(pageNo);
        // setIsFetching(true);
        setIsFetching(initialmanifestLength === normalManifestList.length);
      }



      return (
        <div>
          {
            manifestList.map(function(manifest) {
              return (
                <p>{manifest.title}</p>
                )
              }
          }

         //loading spinners
          {isFetching && manifestList.length < manifests.length && (
            <div>
               <LoadingIcon />
            </div>
          )}
         </div>
      )
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I wrote some code but its not working perfectly"? What isn't working?

Comment: The above coding does not fetch records till records are there. SInce there is no way to know that if more data is coming from backend.Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:
 - separating component and container. 
 - useRef and IntersectionObserver

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVDiw3lAyp0

Alternatively you can use a lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller